# Overview resources for (rigorous) critical phenomena

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, statistical-physics

I recently came across [this overview](http://www.numdam.org/item/RCP25_1982__30__42_0/) which discusses some results in the theory of critical phenomena. It is already quite old and I would like to know if there are other (more recent) overviews in the same lines of this one.

I am particularly interested (but not restricted to) in the following question. In the physics literature, it is often said that correlation functions of lattice spin systems satisfy a decay:
$$\langle \varphi(x)\varphi(y)\rangle \sim f(|x-y|)e^{-|x-y|/\xi}$$
for some sub-exponential function $f$. Here, $\xi$ is the correlation length. The correlation length is supposed to satisfy $\xi \to \infty$ at criticality, so that at the critical point the above correlation has a decay of the form:
$$\langle \varphi(x)\varphi(y)\rangle \sim \frac{1}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}$$
for some exponent $\alpha$.

I would like to better understand to which degree this is true. More precisely, to which models does this reasoning apply and what rigorous results we already have in this direction.

I am not looking for a paper which proves general results in a 100 pages. Instead, I am looking for an overview which gives the reader some definitions and the basic ideas and points out references where these results were discussed or proved.

Comment: This sounds essentially as a cross posting of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/794258/asymptotic-behavior-of-correlations-at-and-away-from-phase-transition  To make this question useful, it would be good to say what exactly has not been answered already by Yvan in the other post.

Answer (score 2):

Fernández, Fröhlich, and Sokal give an overview of a rigorous analysis of critical phenomena based on random-walk expansions, in their [1992 monograph.](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Random-Walks%2C-Critical-Phenomena%2C-and-Triviality-in-Fern%C3%A1ndez-Fr%C3%B6hlich/d153072f5be193366c79a817349fc7edb8583750)

A field theory approach to fermionic systems is reviewed in [Gentle introduction to rigorous Renormalization Group](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04361) (2021). For a very recent brief overview see [Rigorous renormalization group](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-023-02233-x) (2023).